# glLinkProgram() undefined in program execution even if glew reports that it exists

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I am using a (very) low-end graphics adapter (intel g31).

I am writing an OpenGL program that uses VBOs and shaders (GLSL 1.2). The program compiles flawlessly but then when it calls `glLinkProgram()`, an exception is thrown:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x1027101A (ig4icd32.dll) in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

I used glew's glewinfo.exe and OpenGL Extensions Viewer to see whether `glLinkProgram()` exists -- and it does exists. Also other closely related functions (`glCreateProgram()`, `glCreateShader()`, `glCompileShader()`, etc.) works and works as intended.

What could be the actual source of the problem? Is it a problem or a bug of glew? Is it a problem of my driver?

I have set `glewExperimental` to `GL_TRUE` which solved many of my other problems.

**EDIT:** I have also used `glLinkProgramARB()` and produces the same error as above.

Comment: If glLinkProgram is a function pointer then check if you have initialised the function pointer to a valid function.

Comment: @Ram I have done the necessary initialization: I have called `glewInit()`, and it worked fine (no errors produced).

Comment: Same issue here. I use gl3w, and the compilation of fragment and vertex shaders work fine. The glLinkProgram() crashes exactly as described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that [ig4icd32.dll](http://www.processlibrary.com/directory/files/ig4icd32/402972/) is Intel's driver, and that's where it's crashing, I'm guessing that Intel's driver is crashing.

It shouldn't do that, but don't feel bad. Intel's pretty well known for bad OpenGL drivers. Best to avoid them wherever possible.

Comment: Are there some unofficial driver fixes? I am already using the latest driver. Intel's current OpenGL support, however, is very extensive (especially in Linux).

Comment: @MarkGarcia: I don't know about "unofficial driver fixes" or how that would even work. The GMA-3100 days back to the days when Intel *really* didn't care about driver quality. I'm surprised that it even exposed GL 2.0 APIs at all, let alone has a shader compiler that did something not entirely unlike working. Trying to develop shader-aware applications on such a card is a minefield at best.

Comment: Then I'll try to repair my broken nVidia card. Thanks.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Please note that the open source Linux drivers for Intel GPUs are those with the best quality of all Linux open source GPU drivers. So just saying "the Intel drivers" is a bit misleading. It should be "the Intel proprietary drivers for Windows". To emphase this: Only recently I wrote a direct volume renderer, mostly on my laptop which has a GM45. The shaders work flawlessly and the performance is even much better than on a current low-range NVidia GPU. Also recently Valve went into collaboration with the Linux Intel GPU driver devs to push quality and performance with nice results

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on an Intel mobile 4 express chipset, the shader compiled just fine, but an exception where thrown when linking the actual program, even with trivial vertex or fragment shaders.
I didn't use glew, and in my program the glLinkProgram was called in this way:

```
   ((PFNGLLINKPROGRAMPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glLinkProgram"))(p);
```

Then I solved this issue by firstly getting the pointer, and then calling the actual function.
I don't know why it works in this way.

```
    PFNGLLINKPROGRAMPROC glLinkProgram = ((PFNGLLINKPROGRAMPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glLinkProgram"));
glLinkProgram(p);
```

I try to better debug the first statement, so to find the reason of the program crashing.